# Multiple Prototype Cells are showing fixed height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard, row-height

I am new to IOS, I am trying to make multiple prototype cells in UITableView, but always I am getting same size of rows, no idea why it's behaving like this. I have searched a lot! but no clue, any help will be great for me. Thanks in advance.[This is the image for what I am doing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXFLO.png) and [this is what I am getting as output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I41KV.png).

here is my code for DataSource methods....

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:
   (NSInteger)section
 {
    return 12;
 }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
   cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
     NSInteger count = indexPath.row;
     if(count == 0)
     {
         DetailPostCell *Cell1 = (DetailPostCell *)[tableView 
          dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell1" 
            forIndexPath:indexPath];
       return  Cell1;
    }
    else
    {
         CommentCell *Cell2 = (CommentCell *)[tableView 
          dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell2" 
            forIndexPath:indexPath];
         return Cell2;
     }
 }
```

Comment: note that the size of anything ***in storyboard*** means nothing at all: it's just an indicator for when you're working.  regarding table views and cells, you may have to learn about tableView#heightForRowAt, enjoy!

Comment: @Fattie you mean to say I have to override this method and specify height for each row ?

Comment: sure, I direct you to any tutorial on table views.  say you have two "types" of rows (let's say one is an image and one is a text message).  so, that's totally normal: in that call tableView#heightForRowAt you would basically say "if image, return 190, if message return 75" - or whatever

Comment: For clarity, in all real-world iOS engineering today, you use autolayout.  But to get you started on the learning curve, go ahead and experiment with tableView#heightForRowAt - enjoy

Comment: Wait - are you using objectiveC ?!  you're truly wasting your time.  just click to start a new project in Swift, and enjoy your learning experience!  the "ray wenderlich" tutorials are an OK place to start for hobbyists, enjoy!  tableView#heightForRowAt

Comment: that's right @Fattie it makes sense .... I try this way... Thanks for your time

Comment: @Fattie I am working on an app which is developed in Objective-C that's why my company is demanding me to learn objective c..... once I implement some necessary modules I will shift into swift ..... what do you say ?

Comment: @Fattie for above comment I would say I am using autolayout .. I didn't understand what you said about autolayout and learning curve ...

Comment: In your viewdidload method simply paste these lines

self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 88.0;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

& delete heightForRowAt indexPath: method from your view controller.

Comment: @Virender I have used these lines of code but it make my scrolling inefficient, maybe these lines are making some expensive calls, please explain

Comment: It's better if you can provide your code snippet or related files over here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you didn't set your layoutconstraint properly.

**How?**

Remember to add **top and bottom** constraint at least in **one outlet** in your cell.just like this.
[image]

And 
In your view controller's viewDidLoad.write these two lines.

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 88.0//your estimated height.don't worry it will take what your custom cell want.:)
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Comment: I have added these lines of code but it makes scrolling issues, I mean these lines of code makes some expensive calls which cause performance issues.

Comment: there is no expensive calls and there is no side effect. cross check ur code pls.

Answer (score -1):

Implement the delegate method for setting height of prototype cell, in this case first cell needs some different height than other cells. If you return proper height for each cell the content of cell appear properly.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(indexPath.row == 0) {
        return  //Desired hight of your first cell;
    }
    else {
        return  //Desired hight of your rest cells;
    }
}
```

[result screen shot of comment mention below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IB345.jpg)

Comment: Can u add some explanation about the given code so its better to understand?

Comment: @user2595453 can you please tell me how to calculate desired height ??? because in future I may want to add some more labels and buttons, and labels could be of dynamic height ???

Comment: @Najam Implement delegate method  - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0) {
    return 140.0;
}    put tableview.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension in viewdidload, apply proper constraint to your all subviews in cell so cell can grow if content increases.

Comment: I am attaching the screenshot of example it is working for me for dynamic content please refer the screen shot.